# Can't create iOS simulator

Tags: ios, ipad, ios-simulator

I am trying to create an iOS simulator with iOS 10 on iPad 2.
I went to the dialog which allows us to create new simulators, Then I entered the simulator's name
and the device "iPad 2" in my case.
Now, time to chose an operating system. Since iOS 10 wasn't available by default, I checked the download option on the left and downloaded the version I wanted.
I downloaded iOS 10 as shown below. :

[image]

But when I go back to select the OS I downloaded for my emulator, it doesn't even appear in the drop down.

The same goes for every other simulator I tried to create.
Please does someone know what is wrong ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Max iOS for iPad 2 is iOS 9.x

Best option is to use a device.

If you ***really*** want an iPad 2 simulator, you'll need to use an older version of Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What if I want to run iOS 10 ? I tried selecting  iOS 10 on iPhone 5, 5s, 6 simulators but none matched.

Comment: @DamienDoumer - I don't have any trouble creating iOS 10.3 simulators for iPhone 5 / 5s / 6. It looks like 10.3.1 is the oldest simulator version Xcode 12 supports. You should be developing on **devices** anyway, but particularly if you are targeting iOS versions that old... the simulators are never identical to the devices to begin with.